# How can I execute the query when using GraphQL application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, graphiql

When I try to execute Amplify GraphiQL Explorer via npm run start, it works initially via browser. But when I execute the GraphQL query after for a few seconds I get the following error:

```
Error:
[0] CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set 
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
[0]     at Timeout.connectTimeout [as _onTimeout] 
(C:\Users\username\WebstormProjects\configurationservice\node_modules\serverless-plugin- 
offline-dynamodb-stream\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:69:15)
[0]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
[0]     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
[0]
[0] 1 deprecation found: run 'serverless doctor' for more details
[0] npm run local exited with code 1
```

I dont know the reason and I am concerned about whether I am supposed to use the parameter as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Credentials file in .aws folder should include [default] profile.